# pi as cups server : pings between pi and win10 laptop => host unreachable

Tags: windows, ping, cups

I am a newbie in the raspberry pi world, and I get a problem while trying to use it as a cups server.
  Raspbian is installed, and I put ssh up, I installed cups, and yesterday, I managed to print from my laptop, with the raspberry connected to the printer via USB, and to the laptop via the box's wifi.

Today, it didn't work. The 2 computers (laptop, with windows 10, and the raspberry pi) can't ping each other, but both can ping the box. The two IP are static: 192.168.1.78 for the laptop, and 192.168.1.102 for the other.

here is the result of arp -v -a from the laptop:

```
Interface : 192.168.1.78 --- 0x12
  Adresse Internet      Adresse physique      Type
  192.168.1.64          00-00-00-00-00-00     non valide
  192.168.1.65          9e-97-26-89-30-16     dynamique
  192.168.1.99          00-00-00-00-00-00     non valide
  192.168.1.102         00-00-00-00-00-00     non valide
  192.168.1.254         9c-97-26-89-30-16     dynamique
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statique
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     statique
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     statique
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     statique
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     statique
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     statique
```

I don't know why the physical address is 00-00-00-00-00-00 for xx.xx.xx.102.

here is the content of the file /etc/dhcpcd.conf:
I added at the end:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.102/24
static routers=192.168.1.254
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.254
```

googling didn't help me so far.

thank you

EDIT
here is my router's page concerning the raspberry pi:
[image: router's page]

EDIt
here is the result:
[image: result of ip addr & ip route]

Comment: How is the RasPi connected to the box (I guess that's your internet router)? Is there a DHCP server running on the network? Are there another devices on the network than that three?

Comment: the raspi is connected to the router by wifi, the router provides DHCP but the two IP of the raspi & the laptop are static. there are plenty of devices : computers, smartphones, wifi printers (but not mine, hence the utility of the raspi)

Comment: What ip address range is defined on the DHCP server to serve to connecting devices?

Comment: well, how can I get that information?

Comment: I tried ipconfig /all and I got, among others, these lines:Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.1.78(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Comment: I don't know if it is an answer to your question, it says the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0

Comment: *"I don't know why the physical address is 00-00-00-00-00-00 for xx.xx.xx.102."* ->  I think this indicates that there is an existing arp table entry for the IP, but no one replied to the arp request, which is consistent with ping not working.

Comment: When you can't ping each other then please add the output of these two commands to your question: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: You will have to wait, because I rebooted the router and now all devices can see the others, I will also wait one day or two, but I expected it not to work for a long time. thank you and see you soon for the results you requested!

Comment: I have some news :  # all devices can't see others devices, but they all can see only the router # this behavior vanishes after a router reboot # this behavior appears after some hours (I don't know why). I think it's a router problem, because I hardly see the raspberry to block other devices to see their siblings

Comment: for the 2 statement results, plz see my edit

Comment: It seems that when I put the windows computer in sleep mode, there is something that happens which makes the router something like crashing... no device can see other devices except the network which is seen by all devices.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by comments there is a DHCP server running on your internet router (the box) but it is unclear what ip addresses it serves to connecting devices. This is important if you use static ip addresses. There are many other devices on the network. The DHCP server does not know anything about the static ip addresses and may give them also to another devices. This will break communication of two devices.

The easiest way to avoid this is to let the DHCP server make its work. Don't use static ip addresses. If you really need static ip addresses, maybe for a gateway or a server, then you must exclude these ip addresses from the pool that is managed by the DHCP server so it does not give the same addresses to other devices. How to configure the DHCP ip address pool is a task on the router. Look at it. I can't help much about that because I don't know your router (and it's off topic here).

Comment: I think your answer doesn't apply to me because I specified that the address is static not only in dhcpcd.conf but also in the router's config web page(the first address DHCP has given to raspi was marked as timeless)

Comment: plz see my edit